# Likelihood of no association.

Tags: probability

I am trying to implement object tracking methods described in "Multiple target tracking and identity linking under split, merge and
occlusion of targets and observations" [by anonymous](http://www.cvc.uab.es/~jcrubio/publications/MMTT_ICPRAM2011.pdf). However I am having a hard time.

My motivation is to track bubbles in liquid argon; bubbles can move,split and merge. With simple if statements and distance calculations I can find trajectories when bubbles simply move, hovever a probabalistic aproach is necaserry for more complex cases.

The paper gives description of how to calculate likelihood of a single association between frames. An association could be that the bubble *a* in frame *i* is bubble *c* in frame *i+1*, for example: $p(Y_a|X_a)=\mathcal{N}(|v_a|,\mu,\sigma)$

Where $Y_a$ is the measurments of the association, like centroid positions in both frames, shape, size, orientation and so on, $X_a$ is a binary variable which states whether the asociation is assumed to exist or not, and $v_a$ is just velocity, which we can get from $Y_a$.

My question is, how does $X_a$ come in to play, how do I calculate the likelihood of an association not existing?

Comment: @hardmath yes, that is the paper

Comment: Thanks for the edit, it does give me a better idea of your concern.  I added the link to the body of your Question.